# Azure AD B2C password settings

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

If i am not using the **user flow** to reset the password or create a user in AD B2C tenant with Azure Active Directory Graph then in this scenario where can I set the password policies ? Is there any menifest for this that needs to be updated.

Comment: Is my answer is helpful for you? Any updates from your side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not using user flow, you should be using custom policy.

In this case, if you want to configure password change, you can refetr to [Configure password change using custom policies in Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-password-change), which requires you to update the T**rustframeworkExtensions.xml** file.

If you want to configure the complexity requirements for passwords, see this document: [Configure password complexity using custom policies in Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-password-complexity). You will need to update the **SignUpOrSignIn.xml** file.